# Android: change button image when a different button is clicked

Tags: android, eclipse, image, button, onclick

Every example I could find for changing a button image shows how to change it when that button is clicked. But how would I click a toggle button, and have that click change the image of a regular button?

For a little more detail, I have two buttons, and an onCheckedChanged event:

```
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:text="@string/toggle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/button />

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
if (isChecked)
{
}
```

When the toggle button is pressed and the onCheckedChanged event occurs, I need the background of btn1 to be set to a new image.

Comment: Did you take a look at [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)? It allows you to do define a custom selector as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, more than a week later, there's only one response, and it's wrong. Usually there are 10 posts with the same response to every question; are these forums dead?

Guess I'll answer my own question (I actually did this for an imageButton, but I believe it is the same for a button):

```
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```

Comment: Or if you REALLY want to be fancy how about StateListDrawable :)

Answer (score 0):

on Button Action :

```
 button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(.R.drawable.your_image));
```

Comment: This does not work. I'm assuming using the example above, this would actually be 'btn1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(.R.drawable.your_image));  First error it gives me is for the dot before R.  If I remove that, it says that setBackgroundDrawable has been deprecated.